# Unable to post parameters in Slim PHP

Tags: php, mysql, slim

Today I started to learn about slim php so that I can start post and save datas to mysql. And the problem that Im having right now is that I tried to use the sample code below with this url  `http://localhost/MyRest/index.php/updateScore?id=1&score=36`
but unable to send the parameter. If possible will you provide me with a sample or a tip? I would love to hear from you!

```
$app->post('/updateScore', function() use($app){
    $allPostVars = $app->request->post();
    $score = $allPostVars['score'];
    $id = $allPostVars['id'];

    try 
    {
        $db = getDB();

        $sth = $db->prepare("UPDATE students 
            SET score = :score 
            WHERE student_id = :id");

        $sth->bindParam(':score', $score, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->execute();

        $app->response->setStatus(200);
        $app->response()->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        echo json_encode(array("status" => "success", "code" => 1));
        $db = null;

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $app->response()->setStatus(404);
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From url : `http://localhost/MyRest/index.php/updateScore?id=1&score=36`

You are sending parameter as query string.So it will not get in `post` method. You need `get` method for it.

Please change from :

```
 $allPostVars = $app->request->post();
```

To this :

```
 $allPostVars = $app->request->get();
```

Please refer this : http://docs.slimframework.com/request/variables/

Comment: Thank you! I have one question, Is it possible to use the $app->post('/updateScore')  in url ? Or is it only meant for sending parameters through  codes ?

Comment: Sorry but didn't get you. What you actually want?

Comment: Well, I simply want to use a url like http://localhost/MyRest/index.php/updateScore?id=1&score=36, so that I can pass the parameter to the db, however, I  am unable to send it with the code above, so is the get() only the solution to pass parameter to url  ?

Comment: You can also do like this : `$app->get('/updateScore', function($id,$score)`